# How to make webpack builder create static folder with manually named files?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, build

I'm using as a client framework `Vue.js`.
I encountered the problem which is related to `static` folder. 
Everytime when I execute `npm run build` webpack creates 3 scripts with random generated names.
What I want to do ? For example - `app.f004z0bc24e5bf1b3dcf.js` I'd like to rename to simple `app.js`. So the next time I'm going to build my project, new generated `APP javascript file` would be named `app.js`
Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a webpack feature, and it's pretty handy to prevent users from having cached script.

However if you want to change it, assuming you're using the webpack template,

you can remove the hash from the file name, by editing the `build/webpack.base.config.js` file

look for `output` in your `module.exports` section and change 
`filename: '[name].[hash:7]js',`
to
`filename: '[name].js',`

it should look something like this:

```
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
```

Comment: you can do the same for the asset files if you like, like images, media, fonts etc. in the same file